# Question regarding the dimension of a vector space of all functions from a finite set .

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let, $E=\{1,2,3,....,n\}$ where $n$ is odd positive integer. Let, $V$ be the vector space (over $\mathbb R$) of the set of all possible functions from $E$ to $\mathbb R^3$ under the usual addition and multiplication of functions. Find $\operatorname{dim V} .$

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ Actually, I couldn't try much of the problem but if $n=1$, then obviously, dimension is $3.$
Now, I am thinking about a spanning set to span $V$ and I think $\operatorname{dim V} \leq 3n$ but I am unable to show it .

Comment: How do you get dimension $3$ in the case of $n=1$? What are your three linearly independent functions that span the whole space?

Comment: Sir, those are the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Oh, I misread the question.

Comment: What's the rationale for stipulating that $n$ must be odd?

Comment: @Bungo,I think it has a relation with the next part of the question which I didn't provide .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you’ve figured out that when $n=1$, your vector space has as basis the functions
$$\begin{align*}
f_1\colon\{1\}\to\mathbb{R}^3,&\qquad 1\longmapsto (1,0,0),\\
f_2\colon\{1\}\to\mathbb{R}^3,&\qquad 1\longmapsto (0,1,0),\\
f_3\colon\{1\}\to\mathbb{R}^3,&\qquad 1\longmapsto (0,0,1).
\end{align*}$$

Okay, what happens if $n=3$? Well, we could extend these three functions by making them send $2$ and $3$ to $(0,0,0)$. Will they stay linearly independent if we do that?  If so, can we do something similar with functions that send $1$ and $3$ to $(0,0,0)$, and do something else to $2$? Or send $1$ and $2$ to $(0,0,0)$ and map $3$ to something else? Will the result be linearly independent? Will it span?

Comment: Sir, I think they may not be linearly independent .

Comment: @RabiKumarChakraborty Why not? If $f_1,f_2,f_3$ are as above but send $2$ and $3$ to zero, and $\alpha_1f_1+\alpha_2f_2+\alpha_3f_3$ is the zero function (and so, in particular, sends $1$ to $(0,0,0)$), can $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3$ be different from $0$?

Comment: Okay, Sir, thanks ! I got it .